# Could not invoke JSLint! jslint.vim cannot work in windows 7 (x64)

Tags: javascript, vim, jslint

I use [hallettj / jslint.vim](https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim) on Ubuntu 12.04, everything is ok. but on windows 7(x64), it displays error:

> Error detected while processing function `<SNR>`42_JSLint:
>   line 47:
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect ^@
>
> Error detected while processing function `<SNR>`42_JSLint:
>   line 48:
>   could not invoke JSLint!

I try to solve the problem as follow, but not work:

- rename `jslint.vim/bim/jslint` to `jslint.exe` then add to `PATH`
- modify **jslint.vim** file:

  > " let s:install_dir = expand(":p:h")
  >
  > if has("win32")
  >   let s:install_dir = '"' .
  >   expand("C:\Users\Administrator.vim\bundle\jslint.vim\ftplugin\javascript"). '"'
  >   else
  >   let s:install_dir = expand(":p:h")
  >   endif
- install node.js, npm using `npm install jslint -g` to install jslint om cmd.exe

---

BTW: I adopt [Vindle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) to manage my plugins. 
This is my [**_vimrc**](https://gist.github.com/3604048).

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem. I think that the trick is run-time language, even through setting `language en` in **_vimrc** file is not used.

The solution is:

1. Uninstall the gvim completely.
2. custom install gvim，do NOT check  **Native Language Support** option.
   [image: **Native Language Support** option]
3. So everything is right!